# FullSimplify on TransformedDistribution

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, distributions

**Bug introduced in 8.0.0 and fixed in 10.3.0**

---

Could someone check that I haven't gone mad? I would like to take the maximum of two $[0, 2 \pi]$ independent uniform random variables.

```
distr = 
 TransformedDistribution[
  Max[x, y],
  {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 2 Pi}], 
   y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 2 Pi}]}];
```

`FullSimplify` (and `Simplify`) thinks this is a uniform $[0, 2 \pi]$ distribution:

```
FullSimplify[distr]  (* outputs UniformDistribution[{0, 2 Pi}] *)
```

But if I take the `PDF` of each distribution, I get different answers:

```
PDF[distr, x] // FullSimplify[#, 0 < x < 2 Pi] &  (* returns x/(2 Pi^2) *)
PDF[FullSimplify[distr], x] // FullSimplify[#, 0 < x < 2 Pi] &  (* returns 1/(2 Pi)*)
```

Intuitively, the maximum of two independent uniform random variables will not be uniformly distributed, because it's very unlikely that *both* will be less than $\epsilon$, say.

Is this a bug, or have I misunderstood something? *Mathematica* 10.2 on Mac OS 10.10.

Comment: What if you use `OrderDistribution[]` instead?

Comment: `OrderDistribution` works correctly, agreeing with the above non-`Simplify`ed PDF. Thanks - I wasn't aware of `OrderDistribution`.

Comment: Looks like a bug. I would report it to support@wolfram.com, or I could do that for you.

Comment: I'll do it, thanks. Who around here does the bug header ("bug since 8.0" or whatever)?

Comment: Added the tag; as for the header, let's wait for somebody with an earlier version to chime in before adding it.

Comment: @J.M. The same in v9.0.1

Comment: Given `dist = TransformedDistribution[ blah ]`, what do you think `FullSimplify[ dist ]` should return?  Why is it a meaningful thing to ask for? If you were to ask Mma to `FullSimplify[ PDF[dist,x] ]` ... well, that makes sense because you are full simplifying an expression. But `TransformedDistribution[ blah ]` is just a black box -- it not an expression, so how can you `FullSimplify` it ?  [ This is separate to the fact that  `FullSimplify` gives weird output here. ]

Comment: It makes sense to `FullSimplify[TransformedDistribution[a x, x dist UniformDistribution[{r,s}]]]` to `UniformDistribution[{a r, a s}]`.

Comment: No - `FullSimplify` is doing nothing here. `TransformedDistribution[a x, x dist UniformDistribution[{r,s}]]` returns itself  `UniformDistribution[{a r, a s}]`.

Comment: OK, on my original example let it output `OrderDistribution[{UniformDistribution[{0, 2Pi}], 2}, 2]`.

Comment: Or `TransformedDistribution[
 2 a + 2 b, {a \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
  b \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}]` to `TriangularDistribution[{0, 4}]`

Comment: It is possible to simplify distributions, and `TransformedDistribution` should surely not be expected to do it automatically when eg. `Plus` is not for polynomials.

Comment: `TransformedDistribution` does not ever return a mathematical expression. Rather, it returns a meaningless black box:  EITHER the very same thing you entered, namely  `TransformedDistribution[ blah] ` ... OR in simple well-known cases, it might return another black box e.g. `TransformedDistribution[Exp[u],  u \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[a, b]]` will return the black box:  `LogNormalDistribution[a, b]`. These are not mathematical expressions:  they are just named black boxes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27471/discussion-between-patrick-stevens-and-wolfies).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem arises due to `PiecewiseExpand` operating inside `TransformedDistribution`, similarly to the following

```
pw = PiecewiseExpand[f[Max[x, y], z]]

(* Piecewise[{{f[x, z], x - y >= 0}}, f[y, z]] *)
```

however this kind of transformation is not appropriate when `f` is `TransformedDistribution`

```
pw /. {f -> TransformedDistribution, 
          z -> {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 2 Pi}], 
                y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 2 Pi}]}}

(* UniformDistribution[{0, 2 Pi}] *)
```

Thank you for pointing out this bug. It has been fixed in the development version, so that `FullSimplify` will return the unchanged `TransformedDistribution`.